# Storybook's action() only works when called directly by an event

Tags: javascript, storybook

I'm using Storybook's [action()](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/master/addons/actions/ADVANCED.md) to create an event listener on a component.

This seems to work:

```
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

...

<custom-link-component>
  <a 
    href="https://google.com"
    onBlur={action('blur')}
  >
    Google
  </a>
</custom-link-component>
```

Storybook logs the event in the Actions pane. The code is, however, a little strange, in that `action()` is *invoked*, rather than passed, which isn't the way events usually work. That might be relevant in a moment.

This does NOT work, in that the action is not logged in storybook:

```
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

...

<custom-link-component>
  <a 
    href="https://google.com"
    onBlur={(e) => {console.log(e); action('blur');}}
  >
    Google
  </a>
</custom-link-component>
```

The only difference being that `action()` is invoked inside the anonymous function. `console.log()` fired correctly, however.

I suspect I'm missing something fundamental here, I'm just not sure what. Why is `action('blur')` invoked in the first example? Why doesn't the same `action('blur')` seem to work in the second example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`action('blur')` itself returns an event handler, so you need to now pass the event to it:

```
<a 
  href="https://google.com"
  onBlur={(e) => {
    console.log(e);
    action('blur')(e);
  }}
>
  Google
</a>
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Comment: I lost quite some time, thank you so much!!

Comment: I've been searching on why it's not showing for hours until I've seen this comment thank you. I have another question do I have to add action("")(e) to all eventHandlers to make it appear in the action bar?

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

As explained in the storybook documentation, if you would like to asset invocations during your tests, then you should use the `action()` method:

> Any `args` that are marked as an `action` (typically via `argTypes` or `argTypesRegex`) will be automatically wrapped in
> a [Jest mock function](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestfnimplementation) so you can assert invocations.

## Code Example

If you have an action with these types of signatures (with and without params):

```
// component props
onClose: () => void;
onSubmit: (values: MyData) => void;
```

```
// story object
export default {
  title: 'MyModalWithButton',
  component: MyModalWithButton,
  argTypes: {
    onClose: { description: 'modal closed by user', action: 'onClose' },
    onSubmit: { description: 'modal submitted by user', action: 'onSubmit' },
  },
} as StoryObj<typeof MyModalWithButton>;
```

```
// story args
onClose: action('onClose'),
onSubmit: action('onSubmit'),
```

If you would like the `SyntheticBaseEvent` to be propagated to the `onClose` event, event though it does not have any parameters. You can do this:

```js
// the component
export const MyModalWithButton = (args: MyModalProps) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const onShowModal = () => setModal(true);

  const onCloseModal = (event?: unknown) => {
    setModal(false);
    args.onClose.bind(this, event)(); // propagate SyntheticBaseEvent data
  };

  const onSubmitModal = (values: MyData) => {
    setModal(false);
    args.onSubmit(values); // propagate MyData data
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={onShowModal} data-testid={'open-modal-button'}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      {modal && (
        <MyModal {...args} onClose={onCloseModal} onSubmit={onSubmitModal} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You will now continue to see `SyntheticBaseEvent` and `MyData` on your `Actions` tab.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).