# storybook + jest play method is failing when calling shouldHaveBeenCalled on a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui, storybook

I have this component:

```js
import {
  FC,
  ReactElement,
  useState,
  MouseEvent as ReactMouseEvent,
  ChangeEvent as ReactChangeEvent,
} from 'react';

import { Stack, TablePagination } from '@mui/material';

export const Pagination: FC<IPaginationProps> = ({
  total,
  page = 1,
  rowsPerPage = 25,
  position = 'start',
  rowsPerPageOptions = [10, 25, 50, 100],
  onPageChange,
  onRowsPerPageChange,
}): ReactElement => {
  const [localPage, setPage] = useState(page);
  const [localRowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(rowsPerPage);

  const handleChangePage = (event: ReactMouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | null, newPage: number) => {
    setPage(newPage);
    onPageChange({ page: newPage, total, rowsPerPage: localRowsPerPage });
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (
    event: ReactChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>,
  ) => {
    const perPage = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    setRowsPerPage(perPage);
    setPage(0);
    onRowsPerPageChange({ page: 0, total, rowsPerPage: perPage });
  };

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" justifyContent={`flex-${position}`}>
      <TablePagination
        component="div"
        showFirstButton
        showLastButton
        count={total}
        page={localPage}
        onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        rowsPerPage={localRowsPerPage}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptions}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

I wrote a story for it:

```js
export default {
  title: 'Components/Pagination',
  component: Pagination,
  parameters: {
    actions: {
      handles: ['click'],
    },
  },
  args: {
    total: 100,
    page: 1,
    onPageChange: ({ page }) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log({ page });
    },
    onRowsPerPageChange: ({ rowsPerPage }) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log({ rowsPerPage });
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <div style={{ margin: '3em', boxShadow: '7px 5px 14px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.55)' }}>
        {Story()}
      </div>
    ),
  ],
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Pagination>;


const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Pagination> = ({ ...args }) => <Pagination {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.play = async ({ canvasElement, args }) => {
  const onPageChangeSpy = jest.spyOn(args, 'onPageChange');
  const canvas = await within(canvasElement);

  const prevBtn = canvas.getByLabelText('Go to previous page');
  await userEvent.click(prevBtn);
  await expect(onPageChangeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
};
```

I can see that the button was clicked, and `onPageChange` was called, since the pagination changes accordingly, but the test fails:

> Expected number of calls: >= 1
>
> Received number of calls:    0

And the weirdest thing about it, is that if i click rerun in storybook's interactions tab, everything works.

[image: storybook interactions tab fail]

[image: storybook interactions tab success]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `jest.spyOn` can you not use the standard storybook args? Something like this:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(args.onPageChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
```

For the above to work, you need to make sure your actions are being registered correctly. On the screenshot you attached, I dont see any number next to the `Actions` tab title (it should look like `Actions (1)`, which leads me to believe your actions have not been registered correctly and therefore you will not see them on the `Actions` tab.

For how to register an action, you can see my [description in another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278391/storybooks-action-only-works-when-called-directly-by-an-event/76074463#76074463).

Essentially something like:

```
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

// ...
args: {
  onPageChange: action('onPageChange'),
  //...
},
argTypes: {
  onPageChange: { action: 'onPageChange' },
  //...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jest.spyOn was called too late, after your steps ran. That is why on rerun it will pass - because the previous action exists and it can access it.
It helped for me to move jest.spyOn above Default.play:

```
const onPageChangeSpy = jest.spyOn(args, 'onPageChange'); // replase 'args' with your arguments

Default.play = async ({ canvasElement }) => {
  
  ...
  onPageChangeSpy.mockClear(); //remember to stop spying
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Call it dumbluck but i realized that just changing **`toHaveBeenCalled();`** to **`toHaveBeenCalled;`** worked.